# Oracle: Custome auto-increment: C0001 C0002

Tags: oracle11g, auto-increment

i am trying to create a table in Oracle sql.
I have no trouble creating the table and the sequence i created works fine.
Right now i can use form to dial in name and email and the table will create the PK for me.
The PK ID would looked like this:

```
10001 | xxx | xxxx
10002 | xxx | xxxx
10003 | xxx | xxxx
```

My question is, how can i use function or trigger to auto update my ID, make it into:

```
QWER10001 | xxx | xxxx
QWER10002 | xxx | xxxx
QWER10003 | xxx | xxxx
```

I know how to update it manually, but i want it can put that custom text in front of my ID when i put in information.

the text can be set, no need to change it when the number reach max.

I spend hours looking for solution but can't find the right one, please help!

---

I also did some more research online, right now i have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "PROFILE_T1"
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON "PROFILE"
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.PROFILEID := 'WCCU' sequence.PROFILEIDUSE
END;
```

but this did not work. PROFILEID is the PK and is auto incremented. PROFILEIDUSE is the sequence to make it auto increment. WCCU is the text i want to add to the PK when every data is entered.

Comment: How is the primary key getting inserted currently? My guess is, there is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger which sets it to sequence.nextval. In that case, simply concatenate the text you want to the sequence value. `'QWER'||sequence.nextval`.

Comment: Thank you @Noel you are correct!!! i figured out how to do it now. create or replace trigger "PROFILE_T1"
BEFORE
insert on "PROFILE"
for each row
begin
:new.PROFILEID := 'WCCU' || PROFILEIDUSE.nextval;
end;

Answer (score 0):

create or replace trigger "PROFILE_T1"

BEFORE

insert on "PROFILE"

for each row

begin

:new.PROFILEID := 'WCCU' || PROFILEIDUSE.nextval;

end;

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already created the `sequence`, you simply have to use it in your `INSERT` statement where you should explicitly specify the column value. If you don't want to explicitly specify the value in the `insert` statement, you can use a `before inert` trigger to set the value for the column.

***In INSERT statement***

```
insert into your_table values('QWER'||your_sequence.nextval,....);
```

***Using TRIGGER***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT ON your_table
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   :new.your_primary_key_column := 'QWER' || your_sequence.nextval;
END your_trigger;
```

Now, you can exclude this primary column from your `insert` statement. Trigger will add it for you.